# Fast intersection in Python: what is an _ordered_ alternative to set?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, set, intersection

I need a fast intersection of ordered 'list-like' variables

`set` offers the faster intersection in python, when compared to `numpy.array` or looping a `list`, see timing code below for reference or the numerous posts on intersection on SO ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757698/python-fast-extraction-of-intersections-among-all-possible-2-combinations-in-a), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642763/find-intersection-of-two-lists), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6369527/python-list-intersection-efficiency-generator-or-filter),...)

As `set.intersection` [is a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20100003/whats-the-algorithm-of-set-intersection-in-python), I'd guess it should be applicable in principle to ordered structures.

**Is there an high-speed alternative that I am missing?**

edits: adding the [frozenset solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23529001/ordered-intersection-of-two-lists-in-python), which does appears to be quite fast and maintain the order

---

*Alternatives explored so far*

I. First thing that came to mind is `collections.OrderedDict`, however it does not seem to fit the bill because using a dict would be a waste of space and the keys of an `OrderedDict` don't offer an intersection method, which brings you back to converting them to a `set`.

II. Second option is to use a classic `dict`, intersect on its `keys` and maintain the sorting order in its `values`, however this results in many more operations to extract the sorted values and defeats the idea of doing the sorting off-line in a pre-arranged dictionary.

III. A "nuclear alternative" that came to mind is looping in cython as per this [google groups post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cython-users/tmpDjZHN_8o), however I'd favour a pure-python solution if possible for project guidelines (and admittedly like this other user [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22586543/using-cython-to-speed-up-thousands-of-set-operations) my `C` is a bit rusty)

---

*Timing code for intersection in Python*

```
import numpy as np
import timeit
# === Create some data ========================================================
x_array = np.random.randint(0,1000,100)
y_array = np.random.randint(0,1000,100)
x_set = set(x_array)
y_set = set(y_array)    
x_list = list(x_array)
y_list = list(y_array)
x_frozenset = frozenset(x_list)
y_frozenset = frozenset(y_list)
# === Prepare the test Functions ==============================================
def f_set():
    return x_set.intersection(y_set)
def f_numpy():
    return np.intersect1d(x_array,y_array)
def f_list():
    return [i for i in x_list if i in y_list]      
def f_frozenset_loop():
    return [x for x in x_list if x in y_frozenset]     
def f_frozenset_list_filter_1():
    list(filter(y_frozenset.__contains__, x_list))
def f_frozenset_list_filter_2():    
    return [*filter(y_frozenset.__contains__, x_list)]
# === Output ==================================================================
print('set.intersection          ', timeit.timeit(f_set, number=1000))
print('frozenset/list filter 2   ', timeit.timeit(f_frozenset_list_filter_2, number=1000))
print('frozenset/list filter 1   ', timeit.timeit(f_frozenset_list_filter_1, number=1000))
print('frozenset/list loop       ', timeit.timeit(f_frozenset_loop, number=1000))
print('np.intersect1d            ', timeit.timeit(f_numpy, number=1000))
print('list loop (slooow)        ', timeit.timeit(f_list, number=1000))
```

Output looks like this on my machine currently. There's 1 order of magnitude of difference between set and numpy:

```
set.intersection           0.001270713739261699
frozenset/list loop        0.006882539311596062
frozenset/list filter 2    0.01010412826037355
frozenset/list filter 1    0.019078864781689093
np.intersect1d             0.019451117983342953
list loop (slooow)         0.20725976641605037
```

Comment: try: `[i for i in x_list if i in set(y_list)]` this modifies your last function slightly but should make a big difference because set member testing if O(l)

Comment: How do you choose an order if the orders in the source lists don't match? Eg if `a, b = [5, 2, 0, 3, 4, 1,], [6, 3, 7, 1, 8, 2]` what does `intersect(a, b)` return?

Comment: Thanks Chris_Rands, I'm addint it to the tester. PM 2Ring, the first list used in the intersectin rules the order

Comment: Why not intersect 2 frozensets?

Comment: `frozenset`s are not ordered (they're just immutable)

Comment: @Chris_Rands your optimisation will work better if you pull the `set(y_list)` out of the comprehension and do it first so it is only computed once. Creating a new `set` every time the condition is tested will be worse than searching a list.

Comment: @Duncan Good point, agree completely

Comment: How about `list(filter(frozenset(b).__contains__, a))`, or `[*filter(frozenset(b).__contains__, a)]` in Python 3.6 ?

Comment: Let me add it, see what it looks like

Comment: Looks in line, see results. Would stick with `[x for x in x_list if x in y_frozenset]`. Thanks!

Comment: On a related note, I posted some speed test code & results at [How to find list intersection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697432/how-to-find-list-intersection), but of course that question wasn't concerned with preserving order.

Comment: Ummm...what about list(collections.OrderedDict.fromkeys(itertools.chain(a, b)))?